# JavaFX in VSCode on different systems problem

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-code, javafx, gitignore

I want to use VSCode and JavaFX with a laptop with Linux (Pop.OS) and a Windows11 pc.
If i want to use the javaFx Libary, then i have to write this in the Launch.json:

```
 "vmArgs": "--module-path \"D:/Java/javafx-sdk-21.0.1/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
```

-> it works on PC

Now i Pull it via Github to my Linux but there is a different path to the JavaFx Lib.:

`/home/username/javafx-sdk-21/lib` <- Example

Everytime i have to change the path because of Git. But after changing it works.

I tried to put the .json to the .gitignore but it doesent work.
[.ignore pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE0cJ.png)

I dont use Maven in this case.

```
openjdk 21.0.1 2023-10-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.1+12 (build 21.0.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.1+12 (build 21.0.1+12-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

VsCode

```
Version: 1.85.0 (user setup)
Commit: af28b32d7e553898b2a91af498b1fb666fdebe0c
Datum: 2023-12-06T20:48:09.019Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 25551756
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
Betriebssystem: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

How can i resolve that problem so that i can use on different systems without changing the path everytime? Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: *"I dont use Maven in this case."* -> well, you could use Maven (or Gradle) and then you wouldn't have this issue as those tools can source JavaFX from Maven central and place it on the module path.  Additionally, the project would be useable from the command line or in other IDEs.

Comment: If you didn't want to use Maven, you could put the JavaFX SDK inside your project (probably also checking it into git) and access it via a relative directory rather than an absolute path.  I rarely use VSCode, so did not try it, but I am guessing that would work for you.

Comment: I tried to insert the relative path:
`"vmArgs": "--module-path lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",`

but it doesent work. Yes i put a lib folder in this project with the .jar´s.

Comment: *"lib folder in this project with the .jar´s."* -> The JavaFX SDK libraries contain more than just jar files, they contain native code.  JavaFX will not function without the appropriate native code for your target platform.  It is also confusing to me because your question is tagged *linux and windows*.  The native components for one platform will not work on another.  You would need the native code for all your target platforms available. (With Maven or Gradle dependencies those are picked based on your target platform, so with those tools it "just works").